# differences between native x32 app on x64 windows in compatibility mode and x32 app on x32 windows

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit, native

I got an old native win32 application written in C++ which works fine on windows x32, but it is crashing on Windows x64. Even when I choose compatibility mode. I have a source code, but it is not easy to read, because it is written by some one who is not working in our company anymore, the code is quite large and asynchronous. Not easy tasks to debug.

I would like to know what I should focus on. What is different in x64 windows in x32 compatibility mode in comparision to x32 windows? I know that the registry can make some problems, but it seems that it is not this case. Is there something else?

Comment: Any specific API is having problem? which OS r u trying on?

Comment: how is it crashing? (what error?), where is it crashing (which code?)

Comment: There are pretty close no no discernible differences between true x86 and the wow64 emulated version. I suspect the x32 app is broken too but by chance you get away with it.

Comment: 'x32' does not mean what you think it means. You should use 'x86' here.

Answer (score 5):

These are the steps you need to take to solve your problem:

1. Run it in the debugger.
2. Wait for it to crash.
3. Debug it.

Comment: 4. If you get stuck, post the exact error message and relevant source code to SO and ask for help ;-)